# How to delete a line with specific pattern if exists in a variable

Tags: python, string

I'm using Python paramiko library to run a command remotely and get the output. However, on some servers I am getting login message as well. I want to remove this login message:

```
FILE_OUTPUT = '''
Last login: Mon Nov  9 06:17:39 UTC 2020 from xyz.abc.com on ssh
{'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
'''
```

I am getting the above output. I have truncated the second dictionary part. I want to remove first line if it exists from the variable. I found posts to remove lines from a file, but not from a variable.

Expected output:

```
{'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will find first `{` and last `}` and use `ast` to cast it to dictionary. We can also use `json.loads` but you would have to replace single quotes with double quotes.

```py
import ast

if '{' in FILE_OUTPUT:
    first = FILE_OUTPUT.find('{')
    last = FILE_OUTPUT.rfind('}') + 1

    results = ast.literal_eval(FILE_OUTPUT[first:last])

    print(results)
    # {'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}

    # using json instead of ast.literal_eval
    # assuming `import json`

    results = FILE_OUTPUT[first:last]
    print(json.loads(results.replace('\'','"')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the lines, filtering out the stuff you don't want, then glue them back together (or just keep them as a list of lines).

```py
FILE_OUTPUT = ''.join[line for line in FILE_OUTPUT.splitlines() if not line.startswith('Last login: ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done easily

```py
RESULT = '\n'.join(FILE_OUTPUT.split('\n')[1:])
```

This will skip the first line

If you want to create the string into a dictionary, You can simply edit the code

```py
RESULT = dict('\n'.join(FILE_OUTPUT.split('\n')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
FILE_OUTPUT = '''
              Last login: Mon Nov  9 06:17:39 UTC 2020 from xyz.abc.com on ssh
              {'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
              '''

startjson = [i for i, ele in enumerate(FILE_OUTPUT) if ele == "{"][0] #get index of starting json from string
endjson = [i for i, ele in enumerate(FILE_OUTPUT) if ele == "}"][-1]+1 #get index of ending json from string

data = json.loads(FILE_OUTPUT[startjson:endjson].replace("'", '"')) #need to replace (') as json.loads is recognising json with (") 
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the solution assumed that First line need to be ignored. However, question clearly says if it exists.

```
FILE_OUTPUT = '''
Last login: Mon Nov  9 06:17:39 UTC 2020 from xyz.abc.com on ssh
{'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
'''
for i in FILE_OUTPUT.splitlines():
    if not "Last login" in i:
        print i
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'host_role': 'DB Server'}}
```